# Expo Push Notification Detection

Tags: javascript, react-native, push-notification, notifications, expo

how can i detect when coming notification and make some changes when app is closed...

I'm using **expo-notifications** https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/notifications/

Answer (score 1):

Your app is not notified when it is closed/backgrounded, until the user interacts with it.

From the [Expo 38 release notes](https://blog.expo.io/expo-sdk-38-is-now-available-ab6cd30ca2ee):

> If the notification is triggered while the app is in background,
>
> - it’s presented immediately
> - **the application is not informed of this**
>
> If the notification is triggered while the app is in foreground,
>
> - the application not only receives immediate information about this,
>   but…
> - it can also decide at runtime whether to display a heads-up alert or
>   play a sound! (For more information see the Notification Handler
>   documentation.)

From the [Notifications overview](https://docs.expo.io/push-notifications/overview/), there are 2 listeners:

> addNotificationReceivedListener - This listener is fired whenever a
> notification is received while the app is foregrounded
>
> addNotificationResponseReceivedListener - This listener is fired
> whenever a user taps on or interacts with a notification (works when
> app is foregrounded, backgrounded, or killed)

The [Notifications SDK](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/notifications/) is a good reference as well.